Get access to unmatching events in Apache Flink Cep
I have a Flink Job with CEP pattern.
Pattern example:
// Strict Contiguity
// a b+ c d e
Pattern.begin("a", AfterMatchSkipStrategy.skipPastLastEvent()).where(...)
                .next("b").where(...).oneOrMore()
                .next("c").where(...)
                .next("d").where(...)
                .next("e").where(...);

I have events with wrong order stream on input:
a b d c e

On output I haven`t any matching. But I want have access to events, that not matching.
Can I have access to middle NFA state in CEP pattern, or get some other way to view unmatching events?
Example project with CEP pattern on github
